# Hitting the Done button does not dismiss the View of a MPMoviePlayerController on OS 4.0 beta

Tags: iphone, operating-system, ios4, ipod

Hope someone can help me on this, on the old OS version 3.0 and down , hitting the done button one playing a Video would automatically dismiss the view, but now since we have to control the view appearance, hitting the Done just stops the movie but does not dismiss the view, I tried to check if it was linked to any notification and found that each time the Done button was hit, MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification is triggered the problem is that the same notification is received for any change of state pausing /playing... so dismissing the view when MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification is triggered is not an option. does anyone have an answer for this problem

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

OS 4.0 beta is under NDA, you should not talk about it in SO till its released, you should post this in the apple developer forums, if u think its a bug file one...

Comment: +1 I can attest from personal experience that Apple takes its NDAs very, very seriously. Don't jeopardize your business by being cavalier with your contractual obligations.

Comment: Personal experience? What did you do?

Comment: Yeah I just realize that stupid mistake, thx for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

iPhone OS 4.0 beta is currently under NDA.  I recommend using the [developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/).

However, I will assume the done button does something if not dismiss the view itself.  Check the documentation to see if there is another delegate method or notification that the done button has been pressed so you can dismiss the view yourself.